# Video autoPlay is not working chrome and safari?

Tags: google-chrome, video, safari

I want to make the video autoplay without any user gesture in reactjs. I know as per recent google and apple web video policy we cannot autoplay a video having audio without user gesture.But i have seen few websites which still autoplays the video across modern web browsers also.

I came across many questions related to this issue on stackoverflow but none helped me.

Here is what i have tried.

**Try 1.**

```
<video id="miniVideo" preLoad="yes" autoPlay="autoplay" loop width="100%" height="auto" playsInline>
<source src="/mini/video/cooper.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="/mini/video/cooper.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

**Try 2.**

```
<iframe playsInline id="miniVideo" src="/mini/video/cooper.mp4" width="100%" 
 height="400px"
allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe>
```

**Try 3.**

Script:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var videoTimer = document.getElementById("miniVideo");
    videoTimer.play();
}
```

HTML:

```
<video id="miniVideo" width="100%" height="100%">
<source src="/video/cooper.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<p>This browser does not support the video element.</p>
</video>
```

Your help will be well appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about Safari but Chrome has changed the autoplay policy. Look here:https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

In order to autoplay, add `muted` attributed to `video` tag.
For example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isVideoMuted: true
    };
  }

  handleMuteState = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isVideoMuted: !prevState.isVideoMuted
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <video muted={this.state.isVideoMuted} src="./video.mp4" />
        <button onClick={this.handleMuteState}>{this.state.isVideoMuted ? 'Unmute' : 'Mute'}</button >
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Player;
```

Comment: I had tried this before,didn't work in safari :-/ .thanks for your time bro.

Comment: I can also add that React doesn't seem to add the muted attribute as of now. Check this for more info https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6544