# My mp4 background on web page doesn't always start playing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

i'm creating a portfolio website with React and I have a problem with my mp4 background on the landing page. The problem is that it doesn't always start playing, even if i let it finish loading.

Here is a [demo](https://johndough.netlify.com/), when the video actually plays the clouds in front of the mountain have a subtle movement.

This is the relevant JSX and CSS.

```
import VideoBG from '../media/mountains.mp4';

// ...

<video className="bg-video" loop autoPlay>
    <source src={VideoBG} type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

// ...
```

```
.bg-video{
    position: fixed;
    top: -350px;
    object-fit: contain;
    transition: top .5s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs:Video autoPlay is not working chrome and safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399034/reactjsvideo-autoplay-is-not-working-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: Try muting the video.

Comment: How big is the file? just curious because mp4s (as we all know) can be large files. a 20MB video going thru netlify, being sourced from github repositories, and then loading into a browser, over an internet connection - might cause some delays or loading anomalies.