# HTML5 <video> element not working in React js

Tags: reactjs, video, html5-video

I have converted an HTML template to React js and now I am not able to play the video, have give the attribute `autoPlay="true"`. Still its not working. Can anyone please help me with this?

Below is my video-player code:

```
       return(
            <div>
                <video width="400" controls autoPlay="true">
                <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
                Your browser does not support HTML video.
            </video>
            <p>
            Video courtesy of 
            <a href="<network url of video>" target="_blank">Video is Playing</a>.
            </p>
            </div>
        );
```

The player is opening but none of the controls are working nor the video is playing.
Did I miss to add any package or  tag>? Please let me know.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399034/video-autoplay-is-not-working-chrome-and-safari/52400617#52400617

Answer (score 3):

Chrome stops auto play of all video having audio turned on so you add muted attribute , also add playsinline attribute to play in safari

```
<video width="400" controls autoPlay={true} muted playsInline >
                <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>            
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Goutham J.M.
Got it, now I have to customise video controls.